# How to avoid duplication logic in the code?

Tags: c#

I have two methods:

```
static public async Task Delete( Guid id, string path, ViewModelCollection<ProfileData> collection )       
{                                                                                                          
    var jsonText = await File.ReadAllTextAsync( path );                                                    
    var jsonList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ProfileData>>( jsonText );                           
    if ( jsonList != null && jsonList.Any() )                                                              
    {                                                                                                      
        var itemToDelete = jsonList                                                                        
            .FirstOrDefault( x => x.Id == id );                                                            
                                                                                                           
        if ( itemToDelete != null )                                                                        
        {                                                                                                  
            jsonList.Remove( itemToDelete );                                                               
        }                                                                                                  
    }                                                                                                      
                                                                                                           
    var output = JsonSerializer.Serialize( jsonList );                                                     
    await File.WriteAllTextAsync( path, output );                                                          
                                                                                                           
    var item = collection.FirstOrDefault( x => x.Id == id );                                               
    if ( item != null ) collection.Remove( item );                                                         
}                                                                                                          
                                                                                                           
static public async Task Delete( Guid id, string path, ViewModelCollection<SubscriptionData> collection )  
{                                                                                                          
    var jsonText = await File.ReadAllTextAsync( path );                                                    
    var jsonList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SubscriptionData>>( jsonText );                      
    if ( jsonList != null && jsonList.Any() )                                                              
    {                                                                                                      
        var itemToDelete = jsonList                                                                        
            .FirstOrDefault( x => x.Id == id );                                                            
                                                                                                           
        if ( itemToDelete != null )                                                                        
        {                                                                                                  
            jsonList.Remove( itemToDelete );                                                               
        }                                                                                                  
    }                                                                                                      
                                                                                                           
    var output = JsonSerializer.Serialize( jsonList );                                                     
    await File.WriteAllTextAsync( path, output );                                                          
                                                                                                           
    var item = collection.FirstOrDefault( x => x.Id == id );                                               
    if ( item != null ) collection.Remove( item );                                                         
}
```

The problem, I think, is immediately visible - ProfileData simply changes to SubscriptionData. Question: how to avoid this?

I wanna have this:

```
static public async Task Delete<T>(...){... var itemToDelete = jsonList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id ...)
```

The problem is x.Id of unknown class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The problem is x.Id of unknown class

Declare an interface `IHasId` which defines your `Id` property, and make sure that both `ProfileData` and `SubscriptionData` implement that interface.

You can then [constrain your generic method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint) declaration as follows:

```
static public async Task Delete<T>(...) where T : IHasId
{ ... }
```

(Obviously, if you already have a base class for `ProfileData` and `SubscriptionData` which defines the `Id` property, you can just constrain your generic parameter to that base class.)

Comment: "_you can just constrain you generic parameter to that base class_" Just a matter of personal preference, but in that case I would still make the generic method constrain to an interface an I would make the base class implement that interface.